# ON DELETE CASCADE -- two or more foreign keys required

Tags: mysql, sql

In my private messaging system, I have the following tables:

users, messages, threads, thread_participants

I am trying to set up a sensible foreign key relation.

If all users of a given thread are deleted, I would like that thread, to be deleted. But there could be multiple users of a given thread.

So, if user 1 and user 2 are part of thread.id = 6, and user 1 has there account deleted, I don't want the deletion to cascade down to the threads table until user 2 has also deleted their account. Can I make SQL work for me in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that ON DELETE CASCADE can quite get you what you want.  It will make things easier, however, you will have to use a trigger to get all the way there.  Consider this simple table setup for users, threads, and mappings between them:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int, user_name varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE threads (id int, content varchar(max))

CREATE TABLE users_to_threads (
   user_id int, 
   thread_id int,
   CONSTRAINT FK_U FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTARINT FK_T FOREIGN KEY (thread_id) REFERENCES threads(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Now whenever a user is deleted, their mappings get zapped too.  Then use a trigger to see if you need to delete any threads (I'm pretty sure cascading deletes fire before AFTER triggers fire - if not this solution can still work, just needs a little modification):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_cleanup AFTER DELETE ON users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DELETE threads WHERE id NOT IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM users_to_threads)
END
```

You can probably write up a more efficient query to do that, but you get the general idea.  Note that you *cannot* get clever and put a trigger on the mapping table and then rely on it getting fired by the cascading delete from 'users'.  MySql does not support this, and it doesn't look like they plan on fixing it anytime soon: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11472  Not sure if MariaDB has a fix for it or not, I'm a SQL Server guy myself.